# no such column: accounts_articles.Author_id,

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to get the author of the article from CustomUser Model using ForeignKey but apparently something is missing and I don't know what it is

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False,)
    zip_code = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=5)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, blank=False, max_length=30)

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    Author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)# the problem is here
```

Comment: please add the query that you used?

Comment: I wanted to access the CreateView page related to the Articles model when I got this error, butit was actually a migrations issue, for some reason the changes made were not considered after makemigrations so I had to delete all the migrations and remake them

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add `related_name` to ForeignKey for backward option. You can find this docs
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)
Try it

```
Author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="author")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, The problem for me was the migrations, the changes I made were not taken into consideration when I make the migrations so I just deleted all the migrations files and made them again and it worked perfectly.